# socket.io and redis, node js not working in laravel on homestead vagrant box

Tags: php, node.js, sockets, laravel-5, vagrant

i am using node js, socket.io and redis for publish some message in html   view. but it's not working. when i use simple localhost installed laravel , it's working fine, i did not understand why it's happening with vagrant installed laravel. i share my code, please help.

server side server.js file

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();
var server = require('http').createServer(app);
var io = require('socket.io').listen(server);
var redis = require('redis');

server.listen(3000);
console.log('server listening 3000');

io.sockets.on('connection', function (socket) {

console.log("new client connected");
var redisClient = redis.createClient();
redisClient.subscribe('message');
console.log("redis start");

redisClient.on("message", function(channel, message) {
    console.log("mew message in queue "+ message + "channel");
    socket.emit(channel, message);
  });

  socket.on('disconnect', function() {
    redisClient.quit();
    console.log('redis disconnected!');
  });

 });
```

Client Side

```
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.2.min.js"></script>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-migrate-1.2.1.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.socket.io/socket.io-1.3.4.js"></script>

      <script>
        var socket = io.connect('http://localhost:3000');
        alert('connection');
        socket.on('message', function (data) {
            $(".progress-bar").css('width',+data+'%');
            alert('connection established');
            $("#messages").append( "<p>"+data+"</p>" );
        });
     </script>
```

Controller

```
    class SocketController extends ApiController
    {
         public function testview(){
         return view('courier.socket');
     }

     public function send_message(){
       $count = 90 ;
       for ($i = 0; $i < $count; $i++) {
        Redis::connection();
        Redis::publish('message',$i);
       }
      return 'done';
    }

 }
```

all above code working fine with simple localhost installed laravel 5.2, but it's not working with homestead vagrant box laravel.

Comment: can you explain "Its not working" .. do you have error message, blue screen , what error .... please give as much context as you can to get accurate answers

Comment: http://i.stack.imgur.com/iXtCv.png

Comment: do you forward port 3000 on your VM ? (check your Vagrantfile)

Comment: when set port 3000 in vagrant file, i getting error on console :- events.js:72
        throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
              ^
Error: listen EADDRINUSE

Comment: so forward to another port on your host

Comment: change port 3000 to 8890 but getting same error.

Comment: hum you must have a free/available port on your host, forward the port 3000 of your VM to a free port on your host, change your Vagrantfile to do so

Comment: i also set port in vagrant file :- ports:
    - send: 3000
        to: 3000  ,  but i getting error on console events.js:72
        throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
              ^
Error: listen EADDRINUSE